# Bulk set 'send on behalf of'

Tags: email, exchange-server

I have a service account for an application that is used to send out emails via a MSExchange server. The 'From' field gets populated by the email address in the current users profile, but the server is sending back a response

"SmtpException: Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send on behalf of the from address."

As there are alot of email addresses that could be being sent from, is it possible to set up the service account so that it will have send on behalf permissions for "*@domain1.com email addresses" or do they all have to be added one at a time?

Answer (score 0):

Send on behalf isn't really possible like this given how it's set. If you were OK with Send-As (so the mails would come from Service1@domain1.com versus Service1 on Behalf of bob@domain1.com), you could grant the service account send-as rights at the domain, OU, or mailbox database levels.